# for python versions after 3.4, is it possible to encode IntEnum values by name instead of by numeric values?

Tags: python, json

Starting in python 3.4, the python json serializer serializes IntEnum objects to their numeric value:
see here: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder

is there a way to override this, and use the enum name instead?

overriding the JSONEncoder.default method doesn't help here, as it's called only for types with no json support

Comment: You may need to override the `JSONEncoder.encode` method to manage `IntEnum`s and then let the base method manage the other types

Comment: this is more or less rewriting the json module, I was hoping for a less intrusive method